# How do i check if recordtype exists for Lead

Tags: apex, managed-package

I am developing a managed package. i am accessing leads recordtypeid in my code

```
if (rtypeMap.containsKey(Leads.recordtypeid) && 
    rtypeMap.get(Leads.recordtypeid) != null && 
    String.isNotblank(rtypeMap.get(Leads.recordtypeid).CMFL__Default_Converted_Status__c)){ 
    //Do something
}
```

where Leads is the Lead record
Now this results in a failure while installing in org without recordtype for Leads.

> Leads Missing Organization Feature: Lead.RecordType

Is there a way i can make sure that it works seamless while installing in orgs without recordtypes set for leads?

Comment: @eyescream, question does not looks duplicate to me :)

Comment: @RahulSharma I'd say zachelrath's answer is great. Very detailed, covers lessons learned like availability of that particular rec type for given user... Sure, this question's scope is smaller but if I can point people to strong, well-tested solution... Easy to check afterwards if there are 0 rec types available. Presence of `rtypeMap` in snippet suggests Prady already knows about the rec type describe calls :) For me a perfect answer for just "does it exist" would include an `isAccessible()` check, not only a field describe ;)

Comment: Had seen that question before answering and it seemed different, makes sense now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use describe call to validate if `RecordTypeId` for a object is available. (Recommended method).

   Usually I would use following utility call:

   ```
   public static Boolean isAvailableField(String sObjectAPIName, String fieldAPIName) {
       // call to get the appropriate object's describe
       Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> mapGlobalDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
       Schema.SObjectType objSObjectType = mapGlobalDescribe.get(sObjectAPIName);

       // field describe
       Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = objSObjectType.getDescribe();
       Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapFieldDescribe = 
           objSObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

       // check if field exists in describe call
       return mapFieldDescribe.containsKey(fieldAPIName);
   }
   ```

   And use it to check in my code:

   ```
   // check if field is available
   if(isAvailableField('Lead', 'RecordTypeId')) {
       // using SObject.get method to avoid issues when field is not available
       String recordTypeId = Leads.get('RecordTypeId');
       if (rtypeMap.containsKey(recordTypeId) && 
           rtypeMap.get(recordTypeId) != null && 
           String.isNotblank(rtypeMap.get(recordTypeId).CMFL__Default_Converted_Status__c)){ 
           //Do something
       }
   }
   ```
2. Quick and dirty method: Check with doing `SObject.get` on `RecordTypeId` field, like below:

   ```
   Boolean doesLeadHasRecordType = false;
   // in try catch check if record type is available
   try {
       Object recordtypeId = new Account().get('recordtypeId');
       doesLeadHasRecordType = true;
   } catch(Exception objEx) {
       System.debug('objEx: ' + objEx);
   }
   // using this flag, we know if the object has a record type
   System.debug('doesLeadHasRecordType: ' + doesLeadHasRecordType);
   ```

Note: For package development, always use [`SObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) `get` and `put` methods along with describe calls to make sure features are available before checking.

Comment: Thanks, i will check if this resolves the issue. i am sure this should do it

Comment: Added better example with the first option. Hope it helps!